# How can i send response message to SOAP Outbound Message in Salesforce

Tags: web-services, soap, salesforce, mule, salesforce-service-cloud

I have send Case object details from salesforce to Jira via MULE soft using outbound message. After Create the Case in Jira Salesforce Outbound Message expect some acknowledgement how can i create the acknowledgement. i have used some XML Code to send Outbound Message but its not working its show some error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="<a rel="nofollow" class="external free" href="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/</a>" xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <createResponse>
            <result>
                <id>003D000000OY9omIAD</id>
                <success>true</success>
            </result>
            <result>
                <id>001D000000HTK3aIAH</id>
                <success>true</success>
            </result>
        </createResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The Following Error was i have faced
1.SOAP response was a nack
2.org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to d
3.XSD:Boolean Error
How can i solve it these things and correct my XML Code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some tool like the free [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/)  to generate example requests and responses from wsdl. Just install SoapUI, create a new SOAP project with the wsdl from Salesforce, add the generated request to a Mock Service, and let SoapUI generate a Mock Response. There's your example, which should look something like this, with the ? replaced with true/false:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:out="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <out:notificationsResponse>
      <out:Ack>?</out:Ack>
    </out:notificationsResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```